# How to set a variable on functions.php only if the viewed page is the homepage

Tags: wordpress

i am trying to run some PHP code on functions.php to clean some CSSs and add another ones. For now, for testing purpuse i am passing a parameter on the URL and if the parameter is present the code run else, the web load without the PHP code. I need to do a lot of tests on every URL of the site before leave the code running on all the web.
For now, the code is working only for homepage and I want to leave the code running, when i optimize another page i will to add it, etc etc, but I can't use the is_front_page() or is_page() function on functions.php, so what can I do?
I tried adding add_action but this is running after my PHP code, is there a way to use the is_front_page() function on functions.php or i need to change the logic of my code?

Note: I am a developer but I don't know enough about the Wordpress core and how to code in WP.
Note2: I read a lot of questions here and none of them help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code, but maybe it's ok for you to write your code in a function in functions.php and use that function in page.php template?

How does your add_action code looks?
This *should* work too:

```
add_action('get_header', function() {
    if ( is_front_page() ) {    
        // do it
    } 
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. After understand a little bit how the functions.php works, I changed the logic of my code and now it's working. I use the add_action for all the code. Thank you